# Why did Asp.net MVC team choose "../../Content/Site.css" rather than "~/Content/Site.css" in Site.Master page?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The above code shows an external css inclusion tag declared in  Site.Master template.

My question: why did the Asp.net MVC team choose that way rather than using "~/Content/Site.css" ?

Is it the best practice? I am sorry, I am a newbie and still learning to improve my skill.

EDIT 1: I want to make it clearer that "~/" must be passed in to url-resolving method first. Thus, I can rewrite my question as follows:

> Why did the team choose "../.." rather than "~/" resolved by url resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by MVC 3 as follows: I think the MVC team has read this question :-)

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Look at this, MVC 3 fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to what @Pauli Østerø said. But, since you asked for a best practice, here it is .. get rid of those hardcoded strings. Use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) for those paths

Comment: T4MVC is a code generator, so it doesn't matter what engine you're using... its like maintaining a class of strings, but instead of doing it by hand its automatically generated for you based on how your actual models, view, routes etc. looks like plus the actual file structure.

Answer (score 1):

~ is a asp.net thing and doesn't make sense in pure html. In webforms that is handled by turning the tag into a server control, that can translate ~ into a absolute path, while you in MVC would have to call some method yourself. Some method being `Server.MapPath` for instance

Comment: Since both MVC and WebForm need the help of IIS to render the HTML output, it does not matter if we use ~/ in MVC too, right? Or there is another consideration taken by the team to choose ../.. rather than ~/?

Comment: like i said... if you write ~ in the html it will just be emitted to the browser, but the browser doesn't know what do do with it.

Comment: But we can use server side html helper to resolve the URL. Or you mean, by using "../../" it will save "energy" of the server?

Comment: eh, no... ~ makes sense in asp.net in general since you can also have virtual directories in MVC, which is what ~ basically means; "resolve the path to the virtual directory im executing in"

Answer (score 1):

Or use "/Content/Site.css", as "/" denotes the site root in html.

Comment: Using / is not portable solution. We never know in the future we have to move the application to be a child application.